# increase the value in the textbox by using arrowkeys

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, arrow-keys

I'm trying to increase the value in the textbox by using arrowkeys. I'm using wfp, c#

```
if (ke.Key == Key.Up || ke.Key == Key.Down)
    ke.Handled = false;// need a method in here
```

How can I increase the value in the textbox using arrow keys?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can ı increase the value in the textbox using arrow keys?

Comment: Can you clean up  your question and make it more clear?  Don't provide substantive information in the comments; that belongs in the question.

Comment: okey, i edited it. is that clear now?

Comment: what is the value in textbox. number?

Comment: yes.it contains numbers

Comment: Parse the value and convert it to an integer (or whatever appropriate type if you want to support decimals), increment it, re-assign that value to the textbox.text

Comment: could you write me a little code? sab669

Answer (score 2):

The texbox in WPF

```
 <TextBox Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="0" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="154,138,0,0" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
```

CodeBehind

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int currentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {

        textbox1.Text = (currentNumber + 1).ToString();
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        textbox1.Text = (currentNumber - 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the Syncfusion library is possible, an [`IntegerTextBox`](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/integer-textbox/changing-integer-value) which uses arrow buttons to in-/decrease the value could be used. Minimal and maximal values can be defined in this element too.

```
<Window x:Class="ConTecBrowser.Example"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Example" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <syncfusion:IntegerTextBox ShowSpinButton="True" MinValue="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```